# Unable to read repository at http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-p2-release/content.xml. dl.bintray.com:80 failed to respond

Tags: java, eclipse

Im getting this error when I'm trying to update Eclipse software.
When I try to get the link to open it to a browser it says : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: The bintray service no longer exists (since May 2021 IIRC). You'll need to check with TestNG (or whoever offered this) to see where they migrated to, and/or just remove this update site from your Eclipse configuration.

Comment: What @MarkRotteveel says. See [TestNG Eclipse Marketplace item](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse): the update site moved to [`https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site`](https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site). In the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ update the update site location accordingly.